# TH sound, is it continuant or stop?

Tags: pronunciation, phonology, consonants, sounds

How do you all pronounce the TH sound when speaking fast?

For example, I've learned to pronounce the TH sound like a continuant sound, for example the hard one: ð. I start doing a Z, so this Z go between the the teeth and creates the TH sound. Like a lisp (definition by Macmillan).

But when I speak very fast, the sound becomes like-stop way. That sounds to me like a big difference, it's so different like a "SH" (continuous) and a "CH" (stop).

When I hear native speakers, most of the time their TH sound sounds like a D did behind the upper teeth; I think this Wikipedia did call "Dental Approximant".

But is very confusing to me, because they're three differents sounds, the TH continuant, the TH stop and the TH approximant.

I would really like to pronounce the continuant one, but sometimes it's impossible, sometimes I just stay silent when I don't know what sounds right and natural.
For example when I say, "The Rules" I might use the approximant or the stop, just for shame.

According to Wikipedia, ð is continuous and the others are variations.

I saw people just doing a T or a D between their teeth.
But, this sound more different yet, because I can do a N, L the same way, so this T/D are just T/D in different places.

I saw that sometimes people pronounce approximants on TH beginning words, and continuants on the middle of words.

Are these variations natural, how do you do your TH?
What is considered normal? How do you learn it at school?
   Is it impossible to run away from these variations?
   Does it sound weird if I say "THen" like "ZHen",  the ZH represents a "Z lisp"?

P.S: the unvoiced TH shows these variations:
Continuant is S with a lisp, stop S with lisp and the T dental approximant.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiced_dental_fricative
http://www.ncbi.nlm.nih.gov/pmc/articles/PMC2981115/

Sorry for the errors, I've stopped studying grammar because I just need to learn this first.

Comment: Both [English phonemes](http://www.umich.edu/~jlawler/modestproposal.pdf) spelled TH are fricatives (consonants with continuous friction). TH represents the voiceless interdental fricative phoneme /θ/ in _theocracy, thistle, ether, thigh,_ and _width_, but the voiced interdental fricative phoneme /ð/ in _the other, this, either, thy,_ and _with_ (though _with_ actually swings both ways).

Comment: I see, on the article tables, there are variations by persons or if the TH comes before some consonants or vowels. 
I always heard MOTHER like a MODER with the D between teeth hehe 
Most rarely like MOTHER with TH like Z lisp.
I'm confused.

Comment: John, when you say on the fast speak the TH never changes?
For example, when you say "THE" always sounds like a Z with lisp or sometimes sounds like a D, but a little harder D?
Thank you guys ^^

Comment: There's the sound at the end of *width* and *eighth*, which can be the [voiceless dental non-sibilant affricate](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Voiceless_dental_non-sibilant_affricate). But the other sounds of *"th"* in English get divided into voiced and unvoiced; native English speakers don't perceive any distinctions along the lines of a *"z with lisp"* and a *"harder d"*. Maybe your native language has your ears trained to distinguish between natural variations in the sound of 'th' which English speakers don't hear. If this is the case, you will have to untrain your ears.

Comment: Thank I think I got, I think they are natural variations, because sometimes is impossible to control. 
For example, say fast: "The thirty years war happened in the Seventeenth century."
The TH after "IN" sounds stops, just a 'tap' like a D, but the others THs are continuous.
Thank you, thank you. 
Good luck with the numbers, I love them too.
Loving the number is loving yourself.

Comment: This should be migrated to the Linguistics site. It would probably get better answers there.

Comment: If you're a first language is Spanish, then /ð/ (as in *then*), will sound like a /d/ to you when it occurs between vowels. The reason for this is that in Spanish the voiced stops /b,d,g/ become fricatives when they occur between vowels.  /d/, dental for most Spanish speakers will be realised as a dental fricative [ð], the same as English /ð/. E.g. in /cada vez/ the first word will be realised as [kaða] not [kada]. However, /ð/ in other positions, eg at the beginning of an utterance, won't sound like /d/ like to Spanish speakers because [ð] doesn't occur here as an allophone of /d/ in Spanish.

Comment: Hi Araucaria (South Region?),
I am brazilian. Really, with N is impossible to keep. I am confused because with the stop way TH, sounds like D or T, in the continuous way, I can recognize perfectly. But, the most part sounds T or D.
Thinking sounds Tinking or Though sounds Dou(gh).
Thabk you ^^

Comment: @Araucaria This is often said, but many seem to forget that intravocalic /d/ in Spanish is more often an approximant than a fricative in normal speech, which is never the case with English /ð/.

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet Was going to add */approximant* but, word count, had to delete it (plus couldn't get diacritics). In actual fact, though, /ð/ is most often realised an approximant. The tongue makes dental contact but there is an absence of any kind of frication and the intra-oral pressure does not increase - pretty much exactly the same as Spanish intervocalic /d/. See p.141-2 [here](http://npu.edu.ua/!e-book/book/djvu/A/iif_kgpm_Collins_Phonetics_of_English_and_Dutch_pdf.pdf) (especially top of p. 142). Would have used different source but this is pdf (written by Bev Collins though)

Comment: @Araucaria Sadly, the IPA doesn’t seem to really be able to cope with degrees of lowering—the Spanish approximant /ð̞/ is much laxer than any English /ð̞/ native speakers produce in normal speech. The English one is post-dental to a certain degree, but the Spanish one is both lowered and retracted in comparison, with the only dental contact being often on the _bottom_ side of the tongue. (Spanish shares this typologically unusual place of articulation with Danish /ð/.)

Comment: @JanusBahsJacquet That's very interesting! I still think (in fact I think I've heard Spanish speakers say) that intervocalic /ð/ will sound a bit /d/-like to a Spanish ear. (I'm sure they didn't say '*intervocalic /ð/*' though!) I suppose that would need testing. However, it turns out that Aprendice's Brazilian! I know nothing about Brazilian Portuguese phonetics though - or any Portuguese phonetics, in fact.

Comment: @Aprendice Ah, don't know much about Brazilian Portuguese, I'm afraid! I was wondering where you're living now? I'm wondering if what you're hearing is part of a regional accent? Btw, if you have /n/ before a /ð/ you can pronounce the /ð/ as a /n/! So 'in the end' is often /ɪn ni end/ for native speakers. Quite a lot easier to get your tongue round, especially if your /n/ is already made at the back of your top teeth.

Comment: @Araucaria [Intervocalic voiced stops in Spanish actually become not merely fricatives but indeed ***approximants***](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fonología_del_español): [β̞], [ð̪̞], [ɣ˕].  I’ve marked the ð with both the dental diacritic and the approximant one there. That means the minimal triple *cada cava caga* is very hard for a monoglot native English speaker to catch the differences between. European Portuguese does the same thing with *cada*; I **believe** that Brazilian Portuguese may leave it more as an actual voiced stop, but I could not **swear** that this occurs in all speakers.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In standard English, 'th' is always a dental fricative, a non-stopping, continuous movement of air between the tip of the tongue right and the bottom of the top teeth. It is almost exactly the lisp sound.

It is a rare sound in the world's languages, so most language leaners of English have trouble pronouncing it and attempt to approximate it by the fricatives s/z or the stop t/d.

There are some non-standard varieties of English that use t/d naturally instead of the fricative, like for example Sylvester Stallone in Rocky, or any number of street-wise New Yorkers. So don't emulate this unless you want to sound very urban (and a bit out-of-date)

As with most phonetic things, learning it comes with practice and listening and more practice. For 'th' in particular, a little bit of your tongue sticks past the top teeth, so may feel weird (or even rude depending on your culture).

Comment: Though dialects like Rocky's generally use a dental [t] and [d], to maintain the contrast with normal English alveolar /t/ and /d/.

Comment: Thank you Mitch, I got, when you say very fast, the TH doesn't sound like stop, like a D made between the teeth?
Really John, this dental [t] and [d] I was trying to say hehe
Sometimes is impossible to keep even the dental fricative with stop, just turn in a dental.
I just say the canonical way, when I speak slowly and conscious.
I like how magic they sounds, so perfect hehe,especially when the unvoiced goes to the end of the words. 
Like path...
Thank you guys G_G

Comment: Aprendice, are you a Spanish speaker by any chance? If so, I think I might know what's happening here.

Comment: I've read the http://npu.edu.ua/!e-book/book/djvu/A/iif_kgpm_Collins_Phonetics_of_English_and_Dutch_pdf.pdf
and I understood perfectly.
The perfect TH sound is just a idealization, like the friendly christimas family of TV shows. Very grateful for you.

Comment: With respect, “the lisp sound” has no well-defined meaning. It is a speech defect in which /s/ is not formed the way it is in non-defective speakers, but the range of different sounds generated by this class of error is too broad to pin it to a single realization.

Comment: There’s some difference in actual articulation.  For example, /ð/ is realized as a truly **dental** fricative in many Irish speakers, but as an alveolo-dental fricative for many of the rest of us.

Comment: Aprendice, no matter what your teachers say and no matter what you hear and do, colored by your years of experience with your native language, it's never a stop in standard English, fast or slow, in between vowels, beginning or end of words, or next to other consonants.

Comment: @tchrist,
The lisp sound I referred is according the definition with the Macmillan:

http://www.macmillandictionary.com/dictionary/british/lisp

Mitch, now I'm got confused hehe, 
I really don't how to keep always continuant.
The more clear definition I saw and that was the more specific in my situation, was this:
http://npu.edu.ua/!e-book/book/djvu/A/iif_kgpm_Collins_Phonetics_of_English_and_Dutch_pdf.pdf
p.141-142
That says the TH soft sounds like a fricative, while the hard one, sounds more like a plosive \o/

Thank you for your help guys.

Comment: Aprendice, sorry if I'm not being clear. I do understand that the 'th' is difficult to pronounce correctly if you didn't grow up with it and there will be a great tendency to pronounce it as you do. What I'm trying to tell you as that to remove you _confusion_, things are as I said, 'th' is never a stop. That is not confusing at all. It is still very difficult for you, I get that. It's just very simple,'th' is always a fricative. Difficult to do but very easy to understand. If you find yourself wanting to do 'th' as a stop (plosive) then that is wrong. Always a fricative. Never a stop. Easy.

Comment: Thank you Mitch, I really not worried now. I'm just talking without worry.
Problem solved.
Very thank you for you all and good studies.